# Build error on Zapp when running iPhone app (with KIF testsuites)

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, integration-testing, kif-framework

I am working on a sample project for testing KIF framework and Zapp. The project (with Directory scheme and Integration Tests scheme) builds fine on XCode and runs on Simulator.

The GitHub url for the project is here: https://github.com/dolphyfernandes/DirectoryApp

I am trying to run Zapp for continuous Integration (CI). The project when run via Zapp with Directory scheme runs fine. But when I update the scheme drop-down to Integration Tests, the build fails.

Below is the error log on the Zapp

```
ld: library not found for -lKIF
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platoform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
** BUILD FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
LD "build/Applications/Directory (Integration Tests).app/Directory (Integration Tests)" normal i386
(1 failure)
```

[image]

Could anyone help me out with this issue? It seems like everything should work fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem.

I had posted the same question on google groups and I got some help over there. The documentation for KIF setup doesn't directly work with Zapp.
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/kif-framework/biRg1-W1O70/vGYWlyAilsEJ

The solution for Zapp to work with KIF is that Zapp project requires to have libKIF.a as a Target Dependency to your app's test target.

You could do the following:

**Step 1:** Drag KIF project under your main project, nested as shown.
[image]  - - - - - ->   [image]

**Step 2:** Click on edit Scheme on top left of XCode and add KIF target to the Build of Test scheme as shown.
[image]

**Step 3:** Add KIF to Target Dependencies by selecting test target > Build Phases and clicking on Add button to add KIF.

This should work fine with Zapp and it now works without any build errors.

Feel free to add to the thread in case of any questions!

Comment: Followed the instructions but I keep getting the same error when trying to build the target from the terminal. ANy tips?

Comment: @leonardoborges .. check the answer! I have posted a link in there. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

@leonardoborges .. I was waiting for you :)

I had prepared this pdf just in case someone would need it. The PDF has detailed step-by-step instructions and hopefully doesn't miss anything.

Have a look at it and let me know if you would need any more information.

http://www.files.com/set/50e715498087f

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the same.. I have uploaded the PDF here.. http://www.files.com/set/50e715498087f